# Pagination works but doesn't reattach javascript / css class on reload

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

Im building a new personal blog and I'm using ajax to post back to a C# Controller to get the results for pagination.
Page 2 loads with the results however, none of the javascript is reloaded because, I believe, when I partially reload the pagination part of the page, it destroys everything in the DOM and because the full page doesn't reload, the javascript isn't invoked.

So I'm looking for a bit of help on working out how to get the external javascript to run again. What it does is adds css classes, gives some fade effects etc.

```
      success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        var page = data
                        $('#blogsContainer').empty();
                        $('#blogsContainer').replaceWith(page);
```

So the success works, I clear out the blogsContainer with the new data.
I'm guessing I need to add a function after the replace to then apply everything that is in an external main.js file.

The main.js file looks like this

```
(function($) {
    var contentWayPoint = function() {
        var i = 0;
        $('.ftco-animate').waypoint( function( direction ) {

            if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('ftco-animated') ) {
                
                i++;

                $(this.element).addClass('item-animate');
                setTimeout(function(){

                    $('body .ftco-animate.item-animate').each(function(k){
                        var el = $(this);
                        setTimeout( function () {
                            var effect = el.data('animate-effect');
                            if ( effect === 'fadeIn') {
                                el.addClass('fadeIn ftco-animated');
                            } else if ( effect === 'fadeInLeft') {
                                el.addClass('fadeInLeft ftco-animated');
                            } else if ( effect === 'fadeInRight') {
                                el.addClass('fadeInRight ftco-animated');
                            } else {
                                el.addClass('fadeInUp ftco-animated');
                            }
                            el.removeClass('item-animate');
                        },  k * 50, 'easeInOutExpo' );
                    });
                    
                }, 100);
                
            }

        } , { offset: '95%' } );
    };
    contentWayPoint();
}
```

The first page has the following applied to it on page load:

```
<div class="col-md-4 d-flex ftco-animate fadeInUp ftco-animated">
    <div class="blog-entry justify-content-end">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

But as you can see, when I press page 2, the div is missing some key css

```
<div class="col-md-4 d-flex ftco-animate">
    <div class="blog-entry justify-content-end">
    </div>  
</div>
```

How would I apply the missing css after the partial reload with ajax?

I hope this is clear what I am trying to do but if not, please just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution may be to re-execute the contentWayPoint() function at the end of the success callback. However, its likely out of scope by then. There are two simple ways to ensure its not :

The cleanest would be to ensure that the code that sets up your pagination is inside the same (function($) {}) block in main.js - that way it will "capture" the function.

The other, dirtier way, would be to change var contentWaypoint= function... to window.contentWaypoint = function - then use window.contentWaypoint() whenever you need to invoke it. THere are much better ways to doing this, but that might get you going.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Andiih. I've moved my pagination code in to the main.js and called the contentWayPoint() function from the success callback and pagination is indeed working.